# Application with BorderPane doesn't display simple button

Tags: java, javafx

very new to JavaFX I'm following a  [simple tutorial here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm)
I created a new JavaFX project but it has a BorderPane as a default rather than a StackPane as the tutorial says, so I left it there.
The application only has a button on it and if I use the BorderPane the button isn't displayed.
If I change it to StackPane the button shows up.
Thinking that for some reason the BorderPane was clipping something off, I made the application windows full size, but I still couldn't see the button.
Here is the code with the BorderPane the one that doesn't display the button:

```
package application;



import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setTitle("This is a test!");
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
            btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    System.out.println("Hello World!");

                }
            });
            root.getChildren().add(btn);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: `root.getChildren().add(btn);` should be `root.setCenter(btn);`

Comment: `BorderPane`'s layout only lays out the five nodes set as `center`, `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left`. So you need to make it one of those - or use a different layout pane.

Comment: Ah OK, thanks. I looked those methods up, but isn't the button a child of root (the panel)? If so, what's wrong with getting all the children (well in this case one child)?

Comment: @antobbo Because the docs about BorderPane say: _BorderPane lays out each child set in the five positions regardless of the child's visible property value; unmanaged children are ignored._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the docs about [`BorderPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html):

> BorderPane lays out children in top, left, right, bottom, and center
>   positions.

Therefore you need to use stuff like:

```
borderPane.setTop(toolbar);
borderPane.setCenter(appContent);
borderPane.setBottom(statusbar);
```

In your case `root.getChildren().add(btn);` should be for example `root.setCenter(btn);`.